# NGRX Effects breaks app on error, how to handle errors?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am using NGRX effects in my app.
When it fails it seems to break the stream.

```
@Effect()
createUser$: Observable<Action> = _action$.ofType(fromUser.CREATE_NEW_USER_ACTION)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((action: fromUser.CreateNewUserAction) =>
      this._tokenService.post('users', action.payload)
        .pipe(
          map(response => {
            this._router.navigate(
              ["dashboard", "users", "view"],
              { queryParams: { id: response.json().message.id } });
            return new fromUser.CreateNewUserCompleteAction(response.json().message);
          },
            catchError(error =>
              of(new fromUser.CreateNewUserFailedAction(error.json().message))
            )
          )
        )
    )
  );
```

The error action is never triggered, I tried logging.

Comment: your brackets seem don't match in pairs, try format your code a bit nicer

Comment: @Xinan yeah, I will

Comment: @Xinan done. Let me know if you find a solution

Comment: Your catch error terminate the observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your tokenService returning?  It might be handling any errors from the API call internally.  CatchError should work as long as your API call is not burying the error event.  If that is the case you may need to throw the error from that service using Observable.throw().

I typically format my effects more like this for readability.

```
@Effect() updateUser$: Observable<Action>;

constructor(action$: Actions, tokenService: TokenService) {
this.updateUser$ = action$.ofType(fromUser.UPDATE_USER_ACTION)
.pipe(
    mergeMap((action: fromUser.UpdateUserAction) => 
        tokenService.patch(`users/${this.user.id}`, action.payload)
           .pipe(
              map(response => {
                 this._router.navigate(
                    ["dashboard", "users", "view"], 
                    { queryParams: { id: response.json().message.id } });
                 return new fromUser.UpdateUserCompleteAction(response.json().message); 
              },
              catchError(error => 
                 of(new fromUser.UpdateUserFailedAction(error.json().message))
              )
           )
        )
    )
);
}
```

This code looks like it should work.  Take a look at your TokenService.

Comment: I get a similar problem when creating the user. If the user email is already taken, my tokenservice is returning`{"type":"error","message":"Email has already been taken"}`.
But the `UserCreateFailedAction` is never called.

Comment: Does the token service return a non 200 http status code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `parentheses` are not correctly placed inside the 2nd `pipe` function. The `map` and the `catchError` should be in **parallel** inside the pipe. In your code, the `catchError` function is inside `map`.

```
@Effect()
createUser$: Observable<Action> = _action$.ofType(fromUser.CREATE_NEW_USER_ACTION)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((action: fromUser.CreateNewUserAction) =>
      this._tokenService.post('users', action.payload)
        .pipe(
          map(response => {
            this._router.navigate(
              ["dashboard", "users", "view"],
              { queryParams: { id: response.json().message.id } });
            return new fromUser.CreateNewUserCompleteAction(response.json().message);
          }),
          catchError(error =>
            of(new fromUser.CreateNewUserFailedAction(error.json().message))
          )
        )
    )
  );
```

BTW, this is a **good** practice placing the `catchError` with the http request rather than put in in the outer `pipe` stream which would potentially stop the `action$` observable and no future actions will be received by the *NGRX* Framework.